# Caption doesn't display correctly

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I've been searching for quite some time to find an answer to my question, but I can't find anything I can use.
When my caption text exceeds the width of the line, it is displayed just like standard text and not as a caption. For example this is a caption for a table, but it behaves exactly the same for figures.

```
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Resultaten van de metingen van het potentiaalverschil \textit{V} tussen de paralleltakken van de brugschakeling op verschillende tijdstippen \textit{t}. \textit{u(t)} = 1 s en \textit{u(V)} = 4 $\mu$V.}
    \label{spanningsmetingen}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
 ...
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Ending a line by \\ doesn't work either. Is there any way I can get this fixed? Thanks!

EDIT: I accidently posted this as an answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\author{Mike}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
Het potentiaalverschil tussen de paralleltakken in de brugschakeling, gemeten door de voltmeter op verschillende tijdstippen, is weergeven in tabel \ref{spanningsmetingen}. De onzekerheid in de waarden is vermeld in het bovenschrift.
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Resultaten van de metingen van het potentiaalverschil \textit{V} tussen de paralleltakken van de brugschakeling op verschillende tijdstippen \textit{t}. \textit{u(t)} = 1 s en \textit{u(V)} = 4 $\mu$V.}
    \label{spanningsmetingen}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \textit{t} (s) & \textit{V} ($\mu$V) \\ \hline
        0                           & 30                       \\ \hline
        20                          & 26                       \\ \hline
        40                          & 26                       \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

This is the source. It is displayed as follows:

[image]

When I shorten the caption, it is displayed like this:

[image]

Do you need anything else? I'm just a beginner as it comes to LateX.

Comment: Can you make the example compilable so we can reproduce your issue? This is certainly not normal.

Comment: Looking at your math, i recommend to read some basic introductory material.

Comment: Concerning the long caption: This will go to the `list of tables` all the way, perhaps causing troubles there. Use the `\caption[short version]{long version}` variant rather

Comment: what do you mean by "not as a caption" a caption is set as a single centred line or as a pargraph if too long. If you said what formatting you wanted the long caption set then someone could tell you what to do. The caption package provides many different layouts.  Unrelated but don't use `\textit` to set mathematics!

Comment: Apparently you have two different accounts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/101725/mike?tab=profile is the other one. Please register, contact the SX staff and get the accounts merged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for I think. As @Johannes_B mentions, you should read some introductory material on LaTeX  - your misconception on how to write math should be corrected. Please compare your own code to my posted answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[a4paper,margin=3cm]{geometry} not needed for this MWE
%\author{Mike}                not needed for this MWE

% \usepackage{pdfpages}       not needed for this MWE
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
% \usepackage{graphicx}       not needed for this MWE
% \usepackage{amsmath}        not needed for this MWE
\usepackage{siunitx}          % for units
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[hang,bf,small]{caption} % added this to format the long caption in a nicer way. Remove the "hang" if you want the caption text to continue in the full textwidth
\usepackage{booktabs} % \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in the table
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}        not needed for this MWE

\begin{document}
Het potentiaalverschil tussen de paralleltakken in de brugschakeling, gemeten door de voltmeter op verschillende tijdstippen, is weergeven in tabel \ref{spanningsmetingen}. De onzekerheid in de waarden is vermeld in het bovenschrift.
\begin{table}[htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Resultaten van de metingen van het potentiaalverschil $V$ tussen de paralleltakken van de brugschakeling op verschillende tijdstippen $t$. 
    $u(t) = \SI{1}{\second}$ en $u(V) = \SI{4}{\micro\volt}$}
    \label{spanningsmetingen}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        $t$ [\si{\second}] & $V$ [\si{\micro\volt}] \\ 
        \midrule
        0                  & 30 \\
        20                 & 26 \\
        40                 & 26 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

producing

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll look into the basics, I've just started using LateX.

Comment: The units are still typeset wrong, both in spacing and shape (units should be upright). I'd recomment you look into the excellent [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package by Joseph Wright, which makes typesetting of units a breeze. Then you can just use `\SI{1}{\second}` and `\SI{4}{\micro\volt}` to get the correct units.

Comment: @hooy I didn't consider the s and V to be units, thus the missing `\SI{}{}`. Normally I would of course typeset all units with `siunitx`

Comment: @Mike What in your text are units and what are mathematical variables?

Comment: @hooy @ Holene Only the 's' and 'micro V' are units. All other things are mathematical variables. I didn't quite know how to get the 'micro' upright, because I could only do this with math notation. I'll look into the package and I'll manage myself.

Comment: @Mike How about the header of the table? As far as I understand your notation, you have two functions, *t(s)* and *V(µ)*, which I read as "t as a function of the variable s" and "V as a function of the variable µ". Or do you mean "Time in seconds" and "Electric potential in micro volts"?